# HTML/CSS Background Image is not flipping

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are two pages:
Index.html and monkey_page.html
Have written a code to flip the index.html to monkey_page.html when the arrow is clicked. and vice-versa on the monkey_page.html code.

Both the pages look fine when checked individually. the flip is also initiated but
Unfortunately, the background image stays and covers the whole screen.

Index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            font-family: Georgia;
        }

        .full-screen {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .flip-container {
            perspective: 1000px; 
            position: absolute; 
        }

        .flipper {
            transition: transform 1s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            position: relative;
        }

        .front {
            z-index: 2;
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
            background-image: url('Background2_1.png');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            display: block;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        .front, .back {
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .back {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .flip-container.full-screen-flip .flipper {
                transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            }

        /* Style for the navigation list */
        .top-nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #14141300;
            padding: 10px 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10; 
        }

        .top-nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .top-nav ul li {
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: fantasy;
        }

        .logo-image , .right-arrow , .central-image {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .logo-image {
            left: 15%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            top: 30px;
            z-index: 10;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #c6988100;
            padding: 25px 0;
            width: 20%;
            /* z-index: 10;  */
        }

        .right-arrow {

            right: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            top: 300px;
            display: flex;
            padding: 25px 0;
            width: 50px;          
        }

        .central-image {
            left: 36%;
            top: 40%;
            width: 370px;
            z-index: 1;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .flip-container.full-screen-flip .flipper .front {
            z-index: 1; 
        }

        .flip-container.full-screen-flip .flipper .back {
            z-index: 2; 
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="flip-container full-screen front" >
        <div class="flipper">
            <!-- Front face content -->
            <div class="front">
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-image">
        
                <img src="side_view.png" alt="Bear with Butterfly" class="central-image"> 
    
                <!-- Image acting as a button for flipping the card -->
                <img src="right_arrow.png" alt="Move to next page" class="right-arrow" onclick="addFlipAnimation(event)">
            </div>
            <!-- Back face content (using iframe to include monkey_page.html) -->
            <div class="back">
                <iframe src="monkey_page.html" frameborder="0" style="height:100%; width:100%"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <script>
    function addFlipAnimation(event) {
         event.preventDefault(); 
        const flipContainer = document.querySelector('.flip-container');
        flipContainer.classList.toggle('full-screen-flip')
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Monkey_page.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title2</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            font-family: Georgia;
        }

        .full-screen {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .flip-container {
            perspective: 1000px; 
            position: absolute; 
        }

        .flipper {
            transition: transform 1s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            position: relative;
        }

        .front {
            z-index: 2;
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
            background-image: url('Monkey_landing.png');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            display: block;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        .front, .back {
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .back {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .flip-container.full-screen-flip .flipper {
                transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            }

        /* Style for the navigation list */
        .top-nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #14141300;
            padding: 10px 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10; 
        }

        .top-nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .top-nav ul li {
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: fantasy;
        }

        .logo-image , .right-arrow , .central-image {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .logo-image {
            left: 15%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            top: 30px;
            z-index: 10;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #c6988100;
            padding: 25px 0;
            width: 20%;
            /* z-index: 10;  */
        }

        .right-arrow {

            right: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            top: 300px;
            display: flex;
            padding: 25px 0;
            width: 50px;          
        }

        .flip-container.full-screen-flip .flipper .front {
            z-index: 1; 
        }

        .flip-container.full-screen-flip .flipper .back {
            z-index: 2; 
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="flip-container full-screen front" >
        <div class="flipper">
            <!-- Front face content -->
            <div class="front">
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Toi Haus Logo" class="logo-image">
        
    
                <!-- Image acting as a button for flipping the card -->
                <img src="right_arrow.png" alt="Move to next page" class="right-arrow" onclick="addFlipAnimation(event)">
            </div>
            <!-- Back face content (using iframe to include index.html) -->
            <div class="back">
                <iframe src="index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:100%; width:100%"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <script>
    function addFlipAnimation(event) {
         event.preventDefault(); 
        const flipContainer = document.querySelector('.flip-container');
        flipContainer.classList.toggle('full-screen-flip')
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any direction would be deeply appreciated. Tried fixing the z-index, also tried removing iframe (but that was messy).

Note: this is my first HTML/CSS code hence pardon the rookie code

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `front` class from the top container, so that it has no background, so it won't *hang* on rotate, and also try changing height and width to viewport units in `.front` and `.back` classes:

```
<div class="flip-container full-screen " >
    <div class="flipper">
```

```
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```